# Подгрузка изображений для энного количество сайтов с одной директории

Tags: wordpress, seo

Есть энное количество сайтов на Wordpress, каждый из них используют одинаковые изображения (примерно 3Гб) соответственно "раздувается" место на хостинге.
Если создать отдельный сайт где будут хранится изображения и прописать подгрузку этих изображений другими сайтами из одной директории.

Как будут реагировать поисковики, если изображения не хранятся в директоии конкретного сайта, а подгружвются для ВСЕХ сайтов из одной конкретной директории на другом хостинге или другом аккаунте?

Как это на SEO может сказаться, или поисковикап параллельно, что десяток сайтов подгружает к статьям изображения из одного места, соответственно имена картинок и Alt тоже одинаковы?

Comment: У вас это все отдельные сайты или мультисайт? Сайты на одном хостинге?

Comment: Поисковик не может, даже теоретически, определить, что два одинаковых изображения с разными url на двух сайтах лежат в одной директории. Зато он может видеть, что изображения идентичны, и имеют одинаковую дату. Это все, что можно сказать по делу. SEO шаманство лучше обсуждать в чатах.

Comment: @Krya  Я так понимаю, вы имели в виду НЕ "Сайты на одном хостинге?", а  "Сайты в одном аккаунте, того-же хостинга". Если так, то частично в одном аккаунте, и в других аккаунтах того-же хостинга.
Но один и тот-же хостинг не может быть проблемой, так как там сотни тысяч сайтов с одинаковой тематикой.

Comment: Для таких целей вы можете использовать мультисайт и заменять урлы под конкретный домен, чтобы картинка была доступа из под каждого домена, но чтобы нормально все это работало через вп медиабиблиотеку нужно будет попариться

Answer (score 0):

плохо будут реагировать. Если у вас ещё и контент вирусной тематики (типо игровое казино, игроферма, майнинг валют и тд.), то выкинут вас пинком под зад из индекса причём очень быстро и все сразу. Гугл любит уникальность.

Comment: @BlackStar1991Странно с 2009 все работает и реагируют не плохо. В топе много страниц.